# How to disable segue when there is no internet connection for iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

To check internet connectivity, I am thinking of updating by AppDelegate with:

1. SystemConfiguration.framework
2. Reachability.h

To stop segue, I am thinking of using:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

I only want to show alert for no internet connection when user taps a UIButton.

What exactly should I do under

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

I have registered for notification under viewDidLoad method in each ViewController where I want to implement internet connectivity checks

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

**reachabilityChanged**

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            break;
        }
        case NotReachable:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"We are unable to make a internet connection at this time. Some functionality will be limited until a connection is made." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];   
            [alert release];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything in `prepareForSegue`.  All you need to do is return false from `shouldPeformSegue` in the event that there is no Internet connection - you can use a boolean property set from your reachability notification method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class interface, declare:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isReachable;
```

In your reachabilityChanged method:

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        { 
            self.isReachable = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            self.isReachable = YES;
            break;
        }
        case NotReachable:
        {
            self.isReachable = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, check if connected to the internet in the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier method.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([identifier isEqualToString:YOUR_IDENTIFIER]) {
    if (!self.isReachable) {
       return NO;
    }
  }
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The app detects perfectly (notification: NotReachable ) when I turn WiFi off on my MacBook Air. But when I turn it back ON, it still posts the notification with NotReachable. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I suggest you try reachability in the real device.  Sometimes simulator does not behave correctly with reachability. If the issue still happens, let me know.